# Create OpenBook Market with 0 decimal spl token

Tags: spl-token

i have created a 0 decimal spl token and i need to Create OpenBook Market on raydium.
My question is how much "minimum order size, and minimum price tick size should i set for 0 decimal token?

Addition info:
Max Supply: 1,000,000
Initial price per token: 1$
Pair: Mytoken/USDC